# Update column with a subquery

Tags: sql

```
ALTER TABLE order_t ADD Totalfixed DECIMAL(7,2);

UPDATE Order_t 
    SET Totalfixed = (
        SELECT orderid, SUM(price * quantity) AS tf 
        FROM
            orderline ol,
            product p
        WHERE
            ol.productid = p.productid 
            AND ol.orderid = orderid
        GROUP BY orderid
    );
```

Everything works fine separately but I get:

> operand should contain 1 column

And if I remove `orderid` from the subquery, I get:

> subquery returns more than 1 row

Is there anyway to make this work without a `join`?

Comment: You should correctly tag your question with the database you are using (SQL Server? or MySQL?).  I removed the extraneous tags and added the more general "sql".  In this specific case, the answer happens to be the same.

Comment: Sorry, and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the database, the context requires a scalar subquery.  This means avoid the `group by` and return only one column:

```
UPDATE Order_t 
    SET Totalfixed = (
        SELECT SUM(price * quantity) AS tf 
        FROM orderline ol JOIN
             product p
             ON ol.productid = p.productid  
        WHERE ol.orderid = Order_t.orderid
     );
```

I also fixed the `JOIN` syntax (*always* use explicit joins) and the correlation clause so it refers to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A 
SET Totalfixed = SUM(price * quantity)
FROM Order_t A 
INNER JOIN orderline ol  ON ol.orderid = A.orderid 
INNER JOIN product p  ON ol.productid = p.productid
```